# Наведение на пункты меню bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

[Стандартное меню Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar):

```js
var $window = $(window);

$window.on('load resize', function(){
  if($(window).width() > 768){
    $('.dropdown').on('mouseenter mouseleave click tap', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
  } else {
    $(".dropdown").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

На десктопе (больше 768px) подменю должно появляться по наведению, а на мобильных девайсах по клику как обычно.

**Вопрос:** как правильно реализовать возможность  раскрытия подменю по наведению только на десктопах?

!Важно. Решение нужно только с jQuery или js, полная имитация добавления класса `open`.

Comment: _возможность раскрытия подменю по наведению_ - при этом клики должны продолжить работать?

Comment: @Grundy, да желательно, чтобы и по клику и по наведению работало как часы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде есть несколько недочетов

1. на каждый обработчик resize, в случае если ширина больше 768 будет добавлять отдельный обработчик для указанных событий, это приводит к тому, что в случае четного количества обработчиков класс open будет добавляться и сразу убираться, таким образом будет казаться, что ничего не происходит.
2. так как обработчик `click` ставит сам бутстрап не нужно ставить его дополнительно вручную
3. кроме класса `open`, при открытии dropdown выполняются еще несколько действий, чтобы не переносить их вручную в свой код, можно воспользоваться методом, который предоставляет bootstrap api: `toggle`

---

Для того, чтобы не добавлялось несколько обработчиков сразу - можно перед навешиванием нового обработчика удалять старые, чтобы не зацепить обработчики установленные не нами, можно воспользоваться [механизмом namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), например:

```
.off('.my-hover') // удалим все обработчики с namespace `.my-hover`
.on('mouseenter.my-hover', function() { // добавим обработчик mouseenter с namespace `.my-hover`
```

---

Из-за скудного api, понять открыт dropdown или нет можно только по наличию класса `open` у родительского элемента (в данном случае `li`). Понимать это нужно для того, чтобы не пытаться открыть dropdown если он уже открыт, так как в данном случае выполнится метод `toggle` - и меню закроется либо наоборот откроется тогда, когда не надо.

В связи с этим придется разделить обработчики `mouseenter` и `mouseleave` добавив в каждый проверку:

если dropdown открыт и происходит `mouseenter` - то ничего не делать

```
.on('mouseenter.my-hover', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) return;
```

если dropdown закрыт и происходит `mouseleave` - то ничего не делать

```
.on('mouseleave.my-hover', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) return;
```

Далее в обработчике останется только получить объект dropdown, взять его можно с помощью одноименной функции на элементе с атрибутом `data-toggle="dropdown"` и выполнить функцию `toggle`

```
$(this).find('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown('toggle');
```

---

Пример в сборе:

```js
var $window = $(window);

$window.on('load resize', function() {
  var dd = $('.dropdown')
    .off('.my-hover');
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    dd.on('mouseenter.my-hover', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) return;
        $(this).find('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown('toggle');
      })
      .on('mouseleave.my-hover', function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) return;
        $(this).find('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown('toggle');
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: ого!!! Но при ресайзе у меня все так же перестает работать (((( смотрю тут https://jsbin.com/zogifuh/edit?html,js,output на пару пикселей сузила и пропала возможность наведения)

Comment: @HamSter, ты точный размер смотри :-) наведение работает, по твоему же условию, только если ширина **строго больше** чем `768`. то есть, 769 и больше.

Comment: Смотрю в оба! На уровне 800 - 850px например

Comment: @HamSter, у меня работает, возможно ты не тот размер смотришь :-) ну или что-то не то проверяешь :)

Comment: Такая же ерунда ... навожу - работает, ресайзю - не работает, еще раз ресазю - работает  .... и т.д ...

Comment: @HamSter, без документального подтверждения можно только гадать :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91039/discussion-between-grundy-and-hamster).